# Thieves guild markarth special assignment

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Have done 17 jobs in Markarth however I can't get the special assignment for Markarth. Have all the rest done want to finish thieves guild. On PS4 is this another bug?

Comment: Do you mean the quest 'Silver Lining'? You know you have to speak to Delvoy in Riften, right? *How* can't you get the quest - what do you think is wrong?

Comment: @Joachim you can't take up another assignment before you finish the special assignment when it is available. Vex will tell the player to talk to Delvin first. To me it looks like OP already did the special assignment (but perhaps forgot?) or it is a bug.

Comment: But in order to verify that, we need more information. (Delvin.. yes)

Comment: Yes the silver lining. It has not come up. Have done all other city special but that 1. For some reason it won't come up.